# Configuring WebSocketBundle in Azure with IIS

Tags: php, azure, iis, websocket

I am trying to configure GoS\WebSocketBundle in Symfony2 with php 5.6 using Windows Server 2012/IIS instead buit-in server, i had no problems when i used built-in server in Ubuntu.

Whenever i try to access IIS gives me an 403 error, i already have tried to use SimpleWebSocket Chrome plugin without not success.

I am using the base url  for websocket, ws://my.example.com, i already have tried wss => wss://my.example.com

The server is hosted in Azure, with Websockets enabled.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you host your application on an Azure VM?

Comment: I have not a vm, i am using the preconfigured "Web Application + MySql" pack, it provides me an IIS with PHP support, Azure tells met that the IIS is hosted in a Windows Server 2012, but i can not access to it.

Answer (score 0):

As Web Apps only supports Port 80 for HTTP and Port 443 for HTTPS traffic. Different port configurations will be ignored and traffic will be routed to 80 or 443.

We need to configure an additional port over 80 for WebSocketBundle server. And on local environment, I have to run its command in administrator privileges to raise up websocket server if I set port to 80.

I dived in GOS/WebsocketBundle SDK, and found it used `stream_socket_server()` to raise up websocket server.
So I created a simple test on Azure with the following code snippet:

`<?php
$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:80", $errno, $errstr);
if (!$socket) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
  while ($conn = stream_socket_accept($socket)) {
    fwrite($conn, 'The local time is ' . date('n/j/Y g:i a') . "\n");
    fclose($conn);
  }
  fclose($socket);
}
?>`

The result is that we don’t have the permission to successful run the script.
We can deploy the socket server application on Azure VMs or cloud services as a workaround.